# Как запретить скролл body для мобилок?

Tags: phonegap, mobile-web, html, css

Для компов всегда использовал body {overflow: hidden}. На телефонах не работает - двигаешь пальцем, а он всё равно скроллит. Как запретить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Определить стиль для мобильного устройства с помощью CSS или JS и прописать fixed-позиционирование :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   body {
        position:fixed;
   }
}
```

Возможно понадобится отключение масштабирования для непослушного андроида:

```
@viewport {
  user-zoom: fixed;
}
```

для хтмл:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”user-scalable=no” />
```