# Как можно убрать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки на сайте в телеыонном режиме?

Tags: html, css

Пробовал

```
html { 
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Не работает

Comment: Может body, а не html?

Comment: Подгоняйте верстку элементов так, чтобы они не занимали ширину экрана больше `100vw` (через медиа-запросы, относительной шириной и т.п). Ограничивать через `overflow` — костыль, который рано или поздно вылезет: порежет какой-нибудь контент с текстом наполовину, и всё равно придется разбираться (а пользователь даже на том, что есть, проскроллить и прочитать текст не сможет, потому что заблочен скролл)

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю написанное Владимиром - но если все равно очень хочется получить переполнение контентом границ документа (без скролла), то [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/240547/288409) может помочь. А если не поможет - то надо добавить подробностей о проблеме: раскрыв смысл этого "не работает" в более точный вoпрос о более конкретной проблеме.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
html { 
overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
```